# pyqtgraph weirdness when used with pdb

Tags: python, pdb, pyqtgraph

I was surprised to find the mere existence of a breakpoint can change the behavior of a pyqtgraph object (python2.7).

Here's a minimal working example:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
pg.mkQApp()
pw = pg.PlotWidget()
p1 = pw.plotItem
p1.showAxis('right')
#import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  # Running once with this line, once without
print p1.getAxis('right').rect().width()
```

Run it:

```
# No breakpoint:
% python qtg_pdb_bug.py
0.0
# With breakpoint:
% python qtg_pdb_bug.py
> qtg_pdb_bug.py(7)<module>()
-> print p1.getAxis('right').rect().width()
(Pdb) c
35.0
```

Questions:

1. Out of curiosity: what happens when stopping at a breakpoint which causes this weirdness? Is this a bug in pyqtgraph?
2. Which is the correct/expected result? 0 or 35?

Comment: Well, *I'm* getting a segmentation fault on exit. I think that's the hint to the underlying problem.

Comment: @Veedrac from my experience it's hart *not to get* a segfault on exit with pyqtgraph. Not completely sure that's pyqtgraph's fault though, must be originating in the underlying packages.

Comment: That sounds delightful :P. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. There must be automatic "event-processing" in Qt upon a signal/interrupt (and thus upon a breakpoint).

This emulates it:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui; QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
```